# CIE Delta-E 1994 Algorithm - Input Order

Tags: algorithm, colors, metric

I have implemented the [CIE Delta-E 1994 Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE94) and noticed that changing the order of the input colors changed the output. For the input colors `#ff0000` and `#ffffff` I got ~50.2339 and ~114.5089, depending on the input order.

I have checked online calculators for this metric, such as

- http://colormine.org/delta-e-calculator/cie94
- http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?ColorDifferenceCalc.html

and they return the same results, so I am inclined to believe that I did not make a mistake in my implementation. Intuitively, I would have assumed that the input order was irrelevant, since the algorithm is supposed to compute the difference between the colors.

My questions are:

1. Are these results correct?
2. If so, why does the input order matter and what are the intended semantics of a color difference algorithm that is sensitive to that?

**Update:** I found this note on the site of the second online calculator I linked to above:

> Note that for some of the Delta E methods, the color differences are not symmetric (CIE 1994 and 2000). That is, the difference between Color A and Color B may not be the same as the difference between Color B and Color A. In such cases, one color must be understood to be the reference or standard against which a sample color is compared.

That seems to at least confirm that my results are correct, but I still don't understand how this asymmetry is meaningful or useful in practice. It would be great if someone could shed light on that.